# how do i script to show the car dashing effect?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Actually, I'm developing an endless 3d car runner game made a city view where I'm showing some parked cars so basically what I want is when my player car collides with the parked car I want the parked car to rotate some degree and get back to 0 degree or original position how it was before.

I just wanted to lift the parked car and again should touch the ground back to normal. So this will show some realistic effect in game view.

since I'm new in unity development your help could really help me alot.
what I tried so far is :

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("ParkedCar"))
    {
        Debug.Log("ParkedCar");
        Quaternion from, to;
        float inputValue = 0;
        inputValue += Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * 10 * 1;
        from = transform.rotation;
        to = Quaternion.Euler(0, inputValue, 0);
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from, to, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
    }
}
```

even i have tried this

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("ParkedCar"))
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.right * 100, ForceMode.Impulse);

    }
}
```

trying this but i cant get my parked car collide again on ground. pls help me here.

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried so far in a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) way.

Comment: i tried using addforce & simple transform.rotation, i do have rigidbody attached so i even freezed the position so just rotation can work. it rotate but i couldn't make the parked car collide again on ground. so pls help me here. im scripting this code on the OnTriggerStay() function.

Comment: Okay then i would recommend adding your `OnTriggerStay()` method to your question with what is the behavior at the moment and what is expected. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you correctly you can implement this with a coroutine and `OnTriggerEnter` instead of `OnTriggerStay` like this:

```
private bool isDashed = false;
float time = 1.0f;
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    //Assuming your to quaternion is correct
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("ParkedCar") && !isDashed)
    {
        Debug.Log("ParkedCar");
        Quaternion from, to;
        float inputValue = 0;
        inputValue += Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * 10 * 1;
        from = transform.rotation;
        to = Quaternion.Euler(0, inputValue, 0);
        StartCoroutine(DashingCar(from, to));
    }
}
IEnumerator DashingCar(Quaternion from, Quaternion to)
{ 
    float elapsedTime = 0.0f;       
    while (elapsedTime < time) 
    {
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from, to, elapsedTime / time);
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    isDashed = true;        
}
```